# header text within a table not working

Tags: html, css, email-templates

Im designing a email template and I have two images with text within a table. I want to put a line of text with in the table and above the images. I'm able to do that but the text only aligns with the image on the left and doesnt span the length of both the images. Here is my code:

```html
                       <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" mc:repeatable class="mobileTable">

                          <tr>
                               <div mc:repeatable  mc:edit="top_content">
                            <h1>This is the text</h1>
                          </div>
                          </tr>

                        <tr>

                              <td valign="top" width="33%">

                                <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">

                                  <tr >
                                    <td valign="top" align="center">
                                      <img src="http://gallery.mailchimp.com/653153ae841fd11de66ad181a/images/placeholder_110.gif" style="max-width:110px;" mc:label="image" mc:edit="tiwc150_image00" />
                                      <div mc:edit="tiwc150_content00">
                                        Repeatable content blocks:Repeatable sections 
                                      </div>
                                    </td>
                                  </tr>
                                </table>
                              </td>
                              <td valign="top" width="33%">
                                <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
                                  <tr>
                                    <td valign="top" align="center">
                                      <img src="http://gallery.mailchimp.com/653153ae841fd11de66ad181a/images/placeholder_110.gif" style="max-width:110px;" mc:label="image" mc:edit="tiwc150_image01" />
                                      <div mc:edit="tiwc150_content01">
                                        Repeatable content blocks: Repeatable sections 
                                      </div>
                                    </td>
                                  </tr>
                                </table>
                              </td>
                            </tr>
                          </table>
```

How can I get the text to span the length of the body?

Comment: Any particular reason why you are using a table? This is not tabular data and this can be easily done with CSS without tables.

Comment: @ProfileTwist Most email clients don't render CSS well at all. At this point, writing email templates in tables is your best bet (from my experience)

Comment: @ProfileTwist thats exactly the reason. CSS doesn't work well with every email client

Comment: Good point. Okay see my solution.

Comment: the text seems to span above both images for me, so I'm not sure I understand the issue: http://jsfiddle.net/agentfitz/Qz8En/1/

Comment: It does but once i send the email out it doesn't

Answer (score 0):

```
<tr>
                <th width="100%">
                                    <div mc:repeatable  mc:edit="top_content">
                                    <h1>This is the text</h1>
                                 </div>
                </th>
                          </tr>
```

Replace your first table's row with the code above. it works on IE7.

There are a few suggestions that I have:

- Use `<th>` where possible. I have never tested its use in an email client but I presume it is not any different than a `<td>`
- Consider using pixels dimensions where possible

FYI - I recommend doing the the majority of your testing in the hotmail and gmail clients. Yahoo has superb support of CSS and hotmail does some crazy things. Outlook is nearly impossible to work with (good luck with that client).

Comment: I ended up using this: <caption mc:edit="top_content">Edit Title</caption>